# Skeletons of small categories and the axiom of choice.

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to learn Category Theory and using some lecture notes I found online. They mentioned in passing:

The statement that "Every small category is equivalent to a skeletal category" is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

I am trying to see why this is true and how I can prove it, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Thinking about my comment, I'm fairly confident it can be regarded as an answer, so here goes.

If the axiom of choice holds, then any small category $\mathcal{C}$ has a skeleton. To see this, we simply note that every isomorphism class in $\mathcal{C}$ is a set. Hence we may use $AC$ to choose a single object from each isomorphism class. The resulting full subcategory $\mathcal{D}$ of $\mathcal{C}$ is skeletal. Since we are assuming $AC$ and every object in $\mathcal{C}$ is isomorphic to one in $\mathcal{D}$, the inclusion $\iota: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ is an equivalence.

For the other direction, let $A$ and $B$ be sets, and let $R \subseteq A \times B$. We need to show that $R$ contains a function with the same domain as $R$. Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $R$ by declaring $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$. This is an equivalence relation since it's clearly symmetric, transitive, and reflexive. As such, it defines a groupoid $R$. Choose a skeletal category $\mathcal{C}$ such that there is an equivalence $F: \mathcal{C} \to R$. I claim that the image $F(\mathcal{C}) \subseteq R$ is a function. Let $A,B \in \mathcal{C}$ and suppose $FA=(a,b)$ and $FB=(c,d)$. If $FA \cong FB$, then $a=c$. Since $F$ is an equivalence of categories, there exists a functor $G: R \to \mathcal{C}$ such that 
$$A \cong GF(A) \cong GF(B) \cong B.$$
But $\mathcal{C}$ is skeletal, so if $A \cong B$, then $A=B$. Hence $F(id): FA \to FB$ is the identity, and thus the image of $\mathcal{C}$ is a function. Since $FG(a,b) \cong (a,b)$, that means the first component of $FG(a,b)$ is $a$, so the image of $F$ has the same domain as $R$.

Comment: I think a little more work is needed, because the question was about "Every small category is equivalent to a skeletal category," which doesn't say that the skeletal category is literally a subcategory of the given one. If you define "equivalent" to mean existence of functors in both directions with composites naturally isomorphic to the identity, then one of those functors will send the skeletal category to a skeleton inside the given category, so your proof will apply. [continued in next comment]

Comment: @AndreasBlass I mean any skeletal subcategory (a full subcategory containing a single object from each isomorphism class) of a category $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{C}$ by the inclusion functor.

Comment: [continuation of previous comment] Some people define equivalence of categories to mean the existence of a functor (in just one direction) that is full, faithful, and essentially surjective on objects. With that definition, I don't think your proof would work, but then that definition, though equivalent to the other one in the presence of the axiom of choice, is a disaster in the absence of choice.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I see your concern. I'll add a couple more details

Comment: @AndreasBlass What do you think?

Comment: I agree with your proof that the image of $\mathcal C$ is a function. You still need that it has the same domain as $R$. (That should be part of the statement, at the beginning of the last paragraph, of what needs to be shown; i.e., that's part of what the axiom of choice asserts.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass I think that should be clear from the fact that we have a $G$ such that $GF \cong Id$, no?

Comment: Yes, it should be clear, but it would be good (for the OP) to say so explicitly.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Added

Comment: Thanks everyone for their helpful comments. I am beginning to really like Category theory! I never took any logic classes undergrad or graduate student but this is very intriguing.